# How to create a JavaFX Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

How can I open a JavaFX Maven project from scratch in IntelliJ IDEA? As there is no difference between a Java project and a JavaFx project, I want to open a dedicated JavaFX project (Selection JavaFX from create project Wizard) with Maven module included.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Although dated I'm answering this because I had the same question recently and too many people told me to write my own pom file etc. While that is technically true, it can create more headaches if you aren't careful.

I recommend you:

1. Create a JavaFX project as you normally would.
2. Make sure that project view (dropdown in project structure side tool window) is set to '*Project*' or '*Packages*' (otherwise option in 4th step will not be visible)
3. Then once it is opened and ready right click on the project folder
4. Go to "Add Framework Support...".
5. Check the box for Maven and click "OK".

Let IntelliJ do the work for you at this point.

As for editing FXML files link the IDEA to SceneBuilder.  [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/preparing-for-javafx-application-development.html#d432543e165) is the official documentation. But basically:

1. Install [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/products/).
2. File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaFX
3. Point to the exe file.

To Use: Right click on the FXML file and select "Open In SceneBuilder" (way down at the bottom)

Answer (score 12):

And after all, a program doesn't compiled. So this video helped me: [Configuring Maven For Java FX](https://youtu.be/RVzGvuM5syA)

in words:
we need to move sample.fxml to /resources folder. And in Main.java write:

```
FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
```

Comment: bro I moved the .fxml files to the maven resources folder, still its not getting it

Answer (score 4):

This steps worked for me (Is a different process):
1. Create a maven project.
2. In the generated pom.xml add the following:

```
`<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>your.package.with.mainclass</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>`
```

This adds a maven plugin for javafx (more info: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin)

3. Create in your resources folder your sample.fxml
4. Create your controller class for sample.fxml and link
5. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

It takes me a couple of hours to find the right solution.
Many thanks to this video and the author:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn2tbftFjno

So, following the above video, I would like to recommend:

1. Download JavaFX SDK from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
2. Extract the zip file
3. From the starting page of Intellij IDEA, select Configure/Structure for New Projects
4. Select Platform Settings/Global Libraries
5. Select the plus ("+") button/Java
6. Find the "lib" folder inside your extracted zip file and select all of ".jar" files (except "src.zip"), and then OK
7. Set a new name for the library, let's say "javafx-whatever-version", then 
   Apply/OK
8. Create a JavaFX project as normally.
9. Select File/Project Structure...
10. From Project Settings/Project, remember to select the suitable Project SDK and Project language level
11. From Platform Settings/Global Libraries, right click on the library "javafx-whatever-version" (which you have already added),
    choose Add to modules.../OK
12. Switch to Project Settings/Modules, choose Apply/OK
13. Back to your project manager, right click on "src"/New/module-info.java
14. Add new lines to the body of module-info.java:

```
requires javafx.fxml; 
requires javafx.controls; 
opens sample;
```

15. Run the project and enjoy!

Comment: This appears to be a useful answer for a project which in not based on Maven.  I suspect, if Maven were involved, the answer would be a little bit different because the Idea Maven integration would already add the required JavaFX libraries to the compile path for project (but not necessarily to the runtime java module system module path).  Perhaps in such a case the answer would be similar to the answers for [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897944/1155209)

Comment: My mistake, thank you @jewelsea for recommendation. Anyway, I hope it will help someone by somehow at least.

Comment: It's a useful recipe to setup a JavaFX project in Idea, it will help someone :-)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here. I think the best answer lies on the [openjfx docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/). It contains a separate section for JavaFX & InteliJ, select the Non modular with Maven section.

Ill describe the steps in breif.

1. Create new Maven project.
2. Select create from archtype.
3. Add new archtype ( groupid : `org.openjfx` , artifactId : `javafx-maven-archetypes` , version 0.0.1 )
4. Select the created archtype and Next.
5. Provide group id `org.openjfx` ArtifactId `hellojavafx` and Next.
6. Change the property archtypeArtifactId value to `javafx-archetype-fxml`.
7. Add new property for javafx version : property `javafx-version` and value : `14`.
8. Finally give a name to project like `HelloJavaFX`.
9. Now click finish and wait for inteliJ to build the project.

Once InteliJ finish its work the pom should look like this [sample](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Non-Modular/Maven/hellofx/pom.xml).

**PS :**
Two more additional tips you need to follow if you follow this approach to get things going smoothly.
JavaFX 14 needs java 11 or newer.
Change the javax maven plugin version to 0.0.1 to 0.0.4 to avoid errors like `invalid flag --module-path`.
Also to work better Download and install the

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Maven, here is the exact user guide below to create a javafx project:

1. Open intellij
2. Create javafx project in folder with other maven projects.
3. Click on folder (project at the top) in intellij and choose run maven and package.
4. Then if you need plugins for javafx click again on project folder, run maven, plugins and you choose. I needed: javafx: jlink.