# JavaFX Project with Maven on IntelliJ Runtime Exception

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I followed [these steps to create a maven project with JavaFX in intelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38639576/3501205).

But, running the project results in a Runtime Exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Valor.CM.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
```

I tried searching, and modifying the main class, but nothing seem to work so far.

**Main.java:**

```
package Valor.CM;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java:**

```
package Valor.CM;

public class Controller {
}
```

**sample.fxml:**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="Valor.CM.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Valor.CM</groupId>
    <artifactId>StopServiceTester</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>
```

Comment: Your sample.fxml path is incorrect: at Valor.CM.Main.start(Main.java:13):

Comment: What should be the correct path?
Right now it's in the same location as the Main and Controller classes.

Comment: The question I asked is no longer relevant to me as I recreated the project using a different method.
I simply ran this command and imported the mvn project to intelliJ: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.zenjava -DarchetypeArtifactId=javafx-basic-archetype`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using

```
Main.class.getResource("sample.fxml")
```

to find the resource. *You shall move the `sample.fxml`* to a folder named `resources` under `src > main` directory of your project.

Comment: I moved the file, but I still get the same exception.

Comment: @AlexWeitz You should ensure that the `Main.class` is in the `src>main>java` folder and then similarily the sample.fxml is in `src>main>resource`. Another way to debug this is using the complete path to the resource on your directory like `/Users/some/folder/some/other/path/to/sample.fxml` which you can get by the file property fo sample.fxml.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't solve the problem and eventually went with a different method for creating a project: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.zenjava -DarchetypeArtifactId=javafx-basic-archetype`